Send Unique email to respective email address using sharepoint folders
I am new to Power Automate. 
I have a folder in sharepoint called " employee documents"(word docs) and another folder in the same sharepoint site called " employee email addresses". The documents names are the "ID" (eg: 123) that are in the employee email addresses file, which is an excel document.
example:
Employee documents 
123(its a word doc)
456((its a word doc)
789(its a word doc)
***123, 456, and 789 are the TITLES of the documents***

Employee Email Addresses (an excel file, i have excel online)
Employee Name | Employee #| Employee Email
Ashley                 | 123             | ashley123@gmail.com 
Maddy                | 456              | maddy1232@gmail.com 

the output is that I want the Employee documents to be sent to the respective email address based on the Employee # in the excel document. So, document 123 will be sent to ashley123@gmail.com .
Please help me, i have been trying to figure this out for 2 days and i can't seem to really understand power automate and how to accomplish this task.
---------------edit 8/7/24***
I accomplished the task using automated flow but i've now been asked to do it as manual flow and for some reason power automate keeps automatically creating "apply to each" and i don't know how to avoid that. Please assist:
enter image description here
enter image description here
last image is the example flow that actually works, automated flow. but since i have to use "get file (properties only) instead of "when a file is created (properties only), i get into an automatic apply to each issue i can't fix or understand.
enter image description here

It would help if you show us run time values for the fields being compared.  Also, it's case sensitive so you may need to convert both sides to upper (or lower) case to be sure.

Troubleshooting 101: Write the comparison values into variables. Use the variables in the condition. Run the flow. Now you can inspect the variables and see what they contain and why the condition goes into the False branch.

@teylyn - i did try adding two compose after the "List files in folder" step and the first compose did inert correctly but the 2nd compose keeps automatically being assigned a "apply to each 2" and i believe this is not what i want. i want the two compose to be right after each other and not in a loop.
i did additional google search and it says to use "initiate a variable" and i did after the "list files in folder" step  that but the same thing happened again, the second "initiate a variable" kept automatically creating a "apply to each 2" step.

@Skin Hi, i'm very new to power automate so please be patient if i ask or say the wrong thing. the file names are literally 1.pdf and etc., all the way to 4 so its not something i can really do case sensitivity check on? the pdf is all PDF.

And there you have it. The second compose or variable gets wrapped in a for each loop. That tells you that the field is not a single value, but a multi value object. Next step in troubleshooting is to open the flow run and inspect the output of the List Files in Folder step. Right now you're flying blind and work on assumptions, which are clearly wrong. Inspect the data, so you can make informed decisions about how to pull items from your data objects.

Hi, @teylyn. thank you for the response, i really appreciate it because i'm very lost. I have now been instructed to do this task a bit differently. so instead of using onedrive, i now have to use two folders in a sharepoint team site - so i am updating my question - thank you!

This is a very ambitious workflow project if you are new to Power Automate. I suggest you start with something simpler and work your way up. There are lots of difficulties in the scenario you describe and it's impossible to address them in one question. Please start your flow and understand how to read the flow run data, so you can understand what data you are working with. Then please start a new question for a single issue that you may run into, and take it one problem at a time.

@teylyn - yeah, it is and i understand what you're saying. my boss asked me to do it so i've been scrambling. I will try to digest how the flow works and etc. thank you!

Hi, I've edited this post, any further help is appreciated. thanks!

Please read this again: When Power Automate generates and "Apply to Each" that means the underlying data is not a single value. Again: you need to understand the data that you are dealing with, otherwise you will not be able to apply the correct tools. Again: study the data in the output of the flow runs. I've said all this before. I'm done here, because you're not applying the advice.
